# Properly Generating Unique Identifier for Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

I did the following in my `model.py` to generate a unique identifier for it:

```
 12 def rand_key(size):
 13     return ''.join([random.choice(string.letters + string.digits) for i in range(size)])
 14 
 15 
 16 class Share(models.Model):
 17 
 20     resource_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
 21     resource_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
 22     resource_content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('resource_content_type', 'resource_object_id')
 23 
 24     identifier = models.CharField(max_length=16,unique=True,default=rand_key(16))
```

The thing is that when a try to save consecutively two records, the error message `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "share_share_identifier_key"` pop up. I'm sure that this is a common feature.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit: Let me just add the the first record is created without any problem and the identifier field has a propoerly "random" value. Is in the cration of the second record that happens the clash. It seems that the `rand_key` function is somehow beeing cached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the output of the random function to the default argument. Then the value will be same for all the entries. Try this code

```
def rand_key(size):
    return ''.join([random.choice(string.letters + string.digits) for i in range(size)])


class Share(models.Model):
    resource_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    resource_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    resource_content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('resource_content_type', 'resource_object_id')
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
        if self.identifier is None:
            self.identifier = rand_key(16)
        models.Model.save(self, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

This will genereate random chars each time a entry is saved.

Answer (score 2):

A couple corrections to Muhammed K K's answer (would have commented but not allowed). This is overriding the models save method and will add the unique ID when the model is saved the first time.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
        if self.identifier is None or len(self.identifier) == 0:
            self.identifier = rand_key(16)
        models.Model.save(self, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

I needed to pass self as the first argument to save and check that the identifier was either an empty string OR null. I don't know what causes these differences or if his answer was not intended to be used vertatim... I'm using Django 1.6 and python 2.6.